# How to get iframeId in a contextMenus onclick event handler?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am developing a Mozilla WebExtension. I want to inject a JavaScript file only into the frame in which I have clicked on the context menu selection created with `contextMenus.create()`.

I am using:

```
browser.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Records",
    "contexts": ["all","link"],
    "id" : "M1",
    "onclick": onClickContextMenu,
}, function() { });

function onClickContextMenu(info, tab){

    var clickedFrameID=""; //How do I get the actual frameId where click occurred?

    browser.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{
                        file: "fileName.js",
                        allFrames: false,
                        frameId: clickedFrameID
                     }, function() {
        console.log("Script injected");
    });
}
```

How to get `clickedFrameID`?

Comment: Yes, I am facing the same issue. Is there any solution? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Sorry sir this, thing I am doing in contextMenus clicked event

                       browser.contextMenus.create({
                            "title": "Records",
                             "contexts": ["all","link"],
                             "id" : "M1",
                            "onclick": onClickContextMenu,
                        }, function() {
                    });

onClickContextMenu in this method I am injecting fileName.js file but here I am not getting frame ID of current iframe
Here I am getting "info" and "tab" object but not iFrameId

Comment: @ChandrakantThakkar Then specify that information in your Question, not just in a comment. As your question is right now it is **too broad** and may be closed. If you want to clearly state (and show in code) that this is executing as a result of a click in a `ContextMenus` item, then this is answerable with a way to do it.

Comment: I have edited your question to include the code you (more-or-less) provided in comments. If that is not what you were trying to communicate, please [edit] the question, or rollback my edit.

Comment: @Makyen this is also correct thing that you have added comment in my question code... Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Making so many testing me (Chandrakant Thakkar) and my team leader Mr. Nitin Makwana got the solution for this situation,

First I have injected "messageListener.js" file in all frames from manifest.json file as

```
"content_scripts": [
{
        "matches": ["https://*/*","http://*/*"],
        "css":["jquery-ui.css"],
        "js": [
            "jquery.js",
            "jquery-ui.js",              
            "content_scripts/msg_listener.js"
        ],
        "all_frames":true
}
```

Then in "messageListener.js" file created "contextMenu" Listener and send message to Background js file when I click contextMenu (Right Click Of Mouse)
as

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", handleContextMenu, false);
function handleContextMenu(event){
     browser.runtime.sendMessage("abc@gmail.com",{type: 
     "onContextMenuClicked", sender:event });
 }
```

here, "abc@gmail.com" is id of my web extension where I want to send message.

Then, In my background js file I have declared on global variable named "clickedFrameID" and in same file I have added onMessage Listener as below

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(msg, sender, callback) {
         if(msg.type === 'onContextMenuClicked')
            {
               if(sender.hasOwnProperty("frameId")){
                   clickedFrameID=sender.frameId;
               }else{
                   clickedFrameID="";
               }
            }
});
```

Now I have injected "fileName.js" file in specific Frame as Below

```
   var clickedFrameID=""; //This is a Global Variable
   browser.contextMenus.create({
     "title": "Records",
     "contexts": ["all","link"],
     "id" : "M1",
     "onclick": onClickContextMenu,
   }, function() { });

 function onClickContextMenu(info, tab){
     var options={};
    if(clickedFrameID !="" && clickedFrameID!=null && 
     clickedFrameID!=undefined )
                    {
                        options={
                        file: "fileName.js",
                        allFrames: false,
                        frameId: clickedFrameID
                      };
                    }


   browser.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,options, function() {
     console.log("Script injected");
   });
 }
```

Now "fileName.js" will be injected in specific frame in that I have right clicked.

Thanks @wOxxOm, @MohammedAshrafali, @Makyen to take interest